# Problem with determining vector in EM

Tags: electromagnetism, calculus

So I came across this equation in my EM book and I would like to determine the vector $L$.

$L$, $p$, $q$ are vectors, $P\times L$ means $P$ cross product $L$ and a is a constant.

$$aL + P \times L = q$$

I've tried to get rid of the product vector but still I couldn't find a way to determine $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a dot product with $P$ to get
$$
a(P\cdot L)= P\cdot q
$$
so we know the component of $L$ parallel to $P$. Now take a cross-product with $P$ so that
$$
a(P\times L)+ P\times(P\times L)= P\times q
$$
or, equivalently
$$
a(P\times L)- |P|^2L - (P\cdot L)P= P\times q,
$$
so
$$
a(q-aL)-|P|^2 L - (P\cdot q)P/a= P\times q
$$
Thus
$$
(a^2+|P|^2)L= aq -  (P\cdot q)P/a- P\times q
$$
Hence $L$.

Comment: Nice @mike stone!  I stand corrected!  :)